# Find the values of $c$ (if they exist) such that the following system has no, unique, and infinite solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

[Please critique my reasoning]

$$x_{1}-2x_{2}+3x_{3} = 2$$
$$x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3} = c$$
$$2x_{1}-x_{2}+4x_{3} = c^{2}.$$

We obtain the augmented matrix,
$$\left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc|c@{}}
1 & -2 & 3 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & c \\
2 & -1 & 4 & c^2
\end{array}\right]$$

and its RREF

$$\left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc|c@{}}
1 & 0 & \frac{5}{3} & \frac{2}{3}c + \frac{2}{3} \\
0 & 1 & -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{c-2}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & c^2 - c
\end{array}\right].$$

Therefore the system will have no solutions for any $c \neq 0, c \neq 1$ (the last row is of the form $[0 0 0 | k], k \neq 0$). Since $x_{3}$ is a free variable, the system cannot have a unique solution. It also follows that the system has infinite solutions whenever $c = 0$ or $c = 1$ (the last row is of the form $[0 0 0 | 0]$)

Comment: the last line right hand side is not $c^2-c,$  it is $c^2 - c - 2$

Comment: always worth checking with actual numbers; in this case, check $c=0,1$ in the original system. We make fewer errors with numbers than with symbols

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your reasoning and answer are fine. (Assuming you've calculated the RREF correctly.)

**Edit:** Will Jaggy points out that it should be $c^2 - c - 2$ in the RREF, instead of $c^2 - c$. In that case, instead of $c \neq 0, 1$, you'll modify that to $c \neq 2, -1$. The remaining goes as it is.

---

In fact, you can note the following for systems of the form $Ax = b$ where $A \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ is a square matrix:

1. Either $Ax = b$ has a unique solution for all $b \in \Bbb R^{n \times 1}$, or
2. For every $b \in \Bbb R^{n \times 1}$, $Ax = b$ either has no solution or infinite solutions.

Comment: in the given rref, the last line right hand side is not $c^2-c,$  correct is $c^2 - c - 2$

Comment: @WillJagy: Thank you, have changed it. (Again, I haven't checked it myself.)